# Getting "Cannot call a method on a null-valued expression" when working with SharePoint in Powershell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I have a VERY annoying problem. It seems Powershell thinks it's appropriate to give me an error without actually telling me what's wrong. I have tried numerous constellations of doing this, all return the same error. Very agitated because of this.

Here is my code

```
$managementWeb = get-spsite http://sp2013dev3:85/sites/wtpublic
$act = "Activities"
$list = $managementWeb.Lists.TryGetList($act)
```

The fault lies in line 3:

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:3 char:1
+ $list = $managementWeb.Lists.TryGetList($act)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

Does anybody see anything wrong with this?

Comment: P.S. I have also tried "get-spweb" in line 1 since lists are normally contained inside spweb objects. this didn't solve my problem, however.

Answer (score 1):

The error means that either `$managementWeb` or `$managementWeb.Lists` is `$null`.

You should check that `Get-SPSite` was successful and actually return an object. If it has, then check whether `.Lists` exists/valid:

```psh
$managementWeb = get-spsite http://sp2013dev3:85/sites/wtpublic
if ($managementWeb -and $managementWeb.Lists) {
    $act = "Activities"
    $list = $managementWeb.Lists.TryGetList($act)
} else {
    # didn't work
}
```

Comment: but my url was correct. if I do this exact same thing through server object model, it works without any problems.

Comment: Are you running it in a SharePoint Managment shell PowerShell session, or have you added the SharePoint PowerShell snapin?

Comment: @LeonidasFett The test above will show you whether it's failing or not. I can't tell why this call would be failing in your particular environment though; I think that's a different question. It's possible you have your `$ErrorPreference` set to `Ignore` or `SilentlyContinue` which might explain why you didn't realize `Get-SPSite` was failing in the first place. If that's the case, you should set your preference back or use `-ErrorAction Stop` and see what error the cmdlet is giving. These are just stabs in the dark based on what's in your post.

Comment: I use spsd, which I think uses a normal PS instance and loads the addins manually.